# Why doesn't this code use the C++ power function directly? Can someone help me with the power function in this code?

Tags: c++

This problem is to output a single integer, the number of possible combinations calculated:

```
int power(int a, int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  // else
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    int temp = power(a, n / 2);
    return temp * temp;
  }
  // else
  return a * power(a, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: I have not understood the question.:)

Comment: Ok this is the question: Find the number of ways that a given integer, can be expressed as the sum of the powers of unique, natural numbers

Comment: What is **your** question?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-power-sum/problem this is the question link

Comment: My question was why we haven't used c++ inbuilt pow function to calculate power, but thanks it is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

This function uses a technique called *exponentation by squaring*.

It's a particularly efficient way of evaluating the power for integral type arguments. The standard C function uses floating point arguments, and the C standard doesn't require an exact result even if the floating point arguments represent whole numbers.

In C++ though you can *probably* rely on one of the overloads of `std::pow` that takes integral type arguments, and cast the result, subject to your making the necessary size checks. **But** again even the C++ standard does **not** require that the best possible result is returned (cf. `std::sqrt` under IEEE754), although one could reasonably regard a `std::pow` function that does not return the correct result for integral arguments to be defective.

Comment: Thanks @Bathsheba as u have said its called exponentiation of squaring I have seen its documentation but it has a different formula other than my code like in my code line7 according to the documentation it should be  int temp = power(a**2, n / 2); similarly in the odd one there is some difference

Comment: It will be sufficiently equivalent. There are various ways of skinning the "exponentation by squaring" cat.

Comment: @AudityaPrratapa The same algorithm can be coded in many different ways. "It's not exactly the same" doesn't mean "it's wrong".

Comment: Yes got it @MaxLanghof thanks